# expression in if condition is returning true for wrong pattern matching (if I'm not wrong)

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to perl. trying the V basic code where i could see that wrong pattern matching was returing true.
Pasting the code here.

```
my @a =["string", 12]; if( $a[0]=~ /(\d+)/ ){  print"anything";}
```

I think program control shouldn't enter the print statement but actually it does.
Didn't understand that how come string has matched with the digit value (\d+).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Your array contains one element, the array reference `["string", 12]`. When the array reference is used as a string, it stringifies to something like `ARRAY(0x1e80cb8)` which contains digits.

To assign two elements, use

```
my @a = ('string', 12);
```

Comment: To clarify for the OP: You get an array of values from `(...)`, but a reference to an array from `[...]`. The reference is just one scalar value, and when assigned to an array, becomes the first and only value in the array.

Comment: @Silvar no, an array is a variable and reference type, not a type of value.  In the correct assignment, there is a list on the right of the `=`.  And even then,  the `()` do not make a list, the comma operator in list context does.  The parentheses are only needed because `=` is higher precedence than `,`

Comment: Re "*You get an array of values from (...)*", No, you simply get the two scalars within. No array; just two scalars on the stack.